# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailerService (?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm trying to configure [this module](https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/docs/mailer.html).

The full error message reads as follows:

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MailerService (?). Please make sure that the argument MAILER_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.`

I keep getting this error out of nowhere, what MAILER_OPTIONS? Where are those options? Nothing is said in the documentation in this respect. Absolutely no idea what's going on.

Here is my AppModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      defaults: {
        from: '"No Reply" <noreply@example.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'templates/pages'),
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
      options: {
        partials: {
          dir: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'templates/partials'),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    MailerService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any ideas?

Here is the service I'm using:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    private readonly mailerService: MailerService,
  ) {}

  public async sendEmail(): Promise<any> {
    const mailDetail: ISendMailOptions = {
      to: 'gutgesagt@yahoo.co.uk',
      from: 'noreply@nestjs.com',
      subject: 'testing Nest MailerModule',
      text: 'test test?!',
      html: '<b>Yahooooo</b>',
    };

    return this.mailerService.sendMail(mailDetail);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove the imported `MailerService` from the `providers` array of your `AppModule`. Only declare providers that are part of the module itself; you would *never* declare an imported provider (service).

```
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
```

Comment: Aaaah, got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered the same error on unit test, maybe you have defined MailerModule in AppModule instead of a separate module, it will make unit test fails because you normally don't import the whole AppModule in unit test. Make sure you defined all the `MailerModule` on a separate module, like `MailModule`, and import this module in the `AppModule`.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    EmailModule
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and

```
imports...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      defaults: {
        from: '"No Reply" <noreply@example.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'templates/pages'),
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
      options: {
        partials: {
          dir: path.join(process.env.PWD, 'templates/partials'),
          options: {
            strict: true,
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  exports: [NestMailerModule],
})
export class EmailModule {}
```

Then also import the module to your RootTestModule

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [...],
      providers: [...],
      imports: [EmailModule],
    }).compile();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just removing MailerService because it is part of the library in node modules and it work for me